# Why it show System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: excel, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\act08\Copy of Copy of test1.xlsx")
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    'each textbox input to excel
    worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    worksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
    worksheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = TextBox3.Text
    'save the input
    workbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    APP.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is the error on? I don't see where you are creating new instances of anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Without the casting, your variables end up as Object which does not have the properties and methods you are expecting from the Excel objects.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim workbook = DirectCast(APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\act08\Copy of Copy of test1.xlsx"), Excel.Workbook)
    Dim worksheet = DirectCast(workbook.Sheets.Item(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    'each textbox input to excel
    Dim cell = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)
    cell.Value = TextBox1.Text
    Dim cell2 = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, 2), Excel.Range)
    cell2.Value = TextBox2.Text
    Dim cell3 = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(2, 1), Excel.Range)
    cell3.Value = TextBox3.Text
    'save the input
    workbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    APP.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: While this is generally good advice, I wouldn't expect a NullReferenceException to arise from not following it.